# Laravel: how to add continue blade syntax inside HTML attributes without space

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

In laravel 5.4, how we can write the following:

`<li class="page-item {{ ($paginator->onFirstPage() ? 'disabled' : '') }}">`

Above is not working, and it shows output as

`<li class="page-itemdisabled">` - If condition is true and

`<li class="page-item ">` - If condition is false.

Notice an space after `page-item` class. I don't want that.

To fix that, I simply tried:

`<li class="page-item{{ ($paginator->onFirstPage() ? 'disabled' : '') }}">`

But the above not working when condition is true and generates output as below:

`<li class="page-itemdisabled">`

Please advise how I can fix this, checked Laravel docs + Googled, but not finding anything such.

Comment: Why don't you just put a space before `disabled` ? It is just a string. Instead of `'disabled'` you can write `' disabled'`

Comment: :( I think that's right. Didn't noticed that small thing, I am new to laravel, so thought it is a problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a space before disabled. Notice the added space below.

```
<li class="page-item{{ ($paginator->onFirstPage() ? ' disabled' : '') }}">
```

Answer (score 1):

you can write

```
<li class="page-item{{ ($paginator->onFirstPage() ? 'disabled' : '') }}">
```

to

```
<li class="page-item{{ ($paginator->onFirstPage() ? ' disabled' : '') }}">
```

Answer (score 1):

Intead of 'disabled' use ' disabled':

```
<li class="page-item{{ ($paginator->onFirstPage() ? ' disabled' : '') }}">
```

Answer (score 1):

You should update your code like:

```
<li class="page-item {{isset($paginator->onFirstPage()) ? 'disabled' : ''}}">
```